# How I can share only in my web site image on facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, share

I want to share in my website image on facebook similar normal upload, with click button..

[this is not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL8RH.jpg) 
[that's exactly what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58zZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the thumbnail image on the link to 1200×627 pixels. Facebook suggests that the minimum image size be 560×292 pixels, but in order for it to work for everyone, it should be 1200×627 pixels. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try that,